# Are you a hypocrite if you don't pray and if you backbite?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, backbiting

Are you a hypocrite if you don't pray and if you backbite?

Answer (score 0):

Of course It is Haram to do backbiting.
You can't said that a Muslim is hypocrite.

If you feel like a hypocrite you can read the link below to know more.
InshaAllah Hope that the article will clear your doubt.
https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/83255/feels-like-a-hypocrite

Comment: Assalamu alaikum, thank you for your answer. I have one more question, is being double-faced and double-tounged make you a hypocrite or is it just haram?

Comment: W'salam. backbiting, double-face,doubles tongue are characteristic of hypocrite. 
Follow the link to know more about hypocrite in islam .  https://www.quranexplorer.com/blog/Education-In-The-Light-Of-Sunnah-And-Qura'an/hypocrites_in_Islam